# How to change href of all links in a page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url-rewriting, preg-replace

I just want to change all the href link when page is loaded. Either using JavaScript or JQuery or any other method.

My links on a page are like

```
<a href="http://example.com/book">
<a href="http://example.com/sheo">
<a href="http://example.com/belt">
```

Into

```
<a href="http://a.example.com/book">
<a href="http://a.example.com/sheo">
<a href="http://a.example.com/belt">
```

Is it possible to use replace(I am just guessing)?
please also see how query string doesn't change, only host name changes.
sorry for confusion.

Comment: Do you mean if you have `http://cnn.com` you want to change it to `http://a.cnn.com`, or is `http://example.com` all there is, because I'm wondering if these answers are jumping the gun?

Comment: And what about, for example, a link to `http://m.example.com/`? As an addenda, with this question, I don't know whether to downvote *everything*, or vote-to-hold as 'unclear what you're asking.'

Comment: I went with voting to hold; seems unfair to punish those trying to help for trying to help with an unclear question.

Comment: well that solve sort of to my problem, but please suggest if i have links with query string. like    http://example.com/college_bookstore/textbook/, also there are lots of links with different query strings but with the same base url example.com

Comment: For future reference, @Racheal, this further bit of information should have been in your original question. It's probably better to accept one of these answers, and then ask a new question to solve this new question.

Comment: @Racheal, how about *you* define your question clearly, and answer the (presumably simple) questions asked by those of us trying to help clarify your problem, and target answers appropriate to your use-case?

Comment: yes, i am really sorry for misunderstanding, i am just tired to search  everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This improves upon Jhecht's answer to allow you to replace the first part of the URL while keeping the second parts:

```
$('a').each(function(i,link){
    var reg = /(http:\/\/example.com\/)(.*)/
    var newlink = link.href.replace(reg, 'http://m.example.com/$2')
    link.href = newlink;
    link.innerHTML = newlink;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/py9fovy4/14/)

Comment: your answer is very close i suppose, i am using  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('a').each(function(i,link){
    var reg = /(http:\/\/example.com\/)(.*)/
    link.href = link.href.replace(reg, 'http://m.example.com/$2');
});

</script>

<a href="http://example.com/the_swaggy_college_bookstore/textbook/" id="gg" style="font-size:36px">test1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/bookstore/textbook1/" id="gg" style="font-size:36px">test2</a>

Comment: @Racheal, I've updated my answer to replace the link text too if that's what you were also after.

Comment: Hello Andy, I have implemented you code it didn't work, i have checked all the code again and again, even in simple test file, it didn't work, i am using latest jquery file also.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there. It works fine in the demo.

Comment: yes it works in demo, i used all the code from there again. have a look. http://prntscr.com/4gxm71

Comment: If you're going to have that code in the head you need to wrap your code in a `document.ready` function, otherwise move the code after your document but before the `</body` tag. See here for updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/py9fovy4/16/

Comment: bingo bingo bingo, it works for mobile too, i mean with my code. you are brilliant man. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Should do what you want, and leave the links trailing the request intact.

```
$('a').each(function(i,link){
    link.href = link.href.replace('http://example.com/','http://a.example.com/');
});
```

Comment: I think this should do your work..

Comment: but how to change with query string.  http://example.com/college_bookstore/textbook/, also there are lots of links with different query strings but with the same base url example.com

Comment: If you are trying to change all of the links in a website that have `'http://example.com/'` in them to `'http://a.example.com/'` then yes, this should work. Without more details, I can't be more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following jquery code in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').attr('href', 'http://a.example.com');
  });
```

Comment: No need to loop each 'a' element.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as:

```
$('a').attr('href','http://a.example.com');
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://a.example.com");
```

Or, if you want those with links to `http://example.com`:

```
$('a[href="http://example.com"]').attr("href", "http://a.example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[href*="Yourpage.html"]').prop('href' , 'http://a.example.com');
});
```